# Alt-click for edge loop

Tags: edges, selection-tools

Hi I am a complete newcomer to blender and am following this tutorial, where he says to alt+click to select an entire row or "edge loop". I have followed all instructions exactly up to this point (3 times to make sure!). Alt-click does nothing. Thank you for your help. p.s. If possible, please keep answers in simple layman's language. I see some similar posts about alt click and loop select but had trouble following since the explanations were too advanced. Thank you!
Video starts where he demonstrates alt+click: https://youtu.be/qqeNA_4O0Qg?t=369

Comment: alt+right click

Answer (score 2):

In version 2.8x Alt+Click is gone.

The way to select a loop is by double clicking.

Comment: Is that out of the box behaviour or are you using a pre-release version of 2.82? In 2.81 I use Alt + LMB as per the manual: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.81/modeling/meshes/selecting.html?highlight=edge%20loops#edge-loops

Answer (score 0):

I also had difficulty following this portion of the tutorial initially, but I got it to work. Things to check:
1. Are you in "Edit Mode"? Otherwise you can't do anything with the mesh
2. Are you in "Vertex Select" mode?
3. Do you have a continuous loop present for your selection? (I'm assuming you're doing the tutorial series, in which case you should have a torus which meets this criterion)

If all of these things are present and you still can't loop select, I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: Hi and thank you for your input. I have a torus (continuous loop), am in edit mode and in vertex select mode but alas have not gotten it to work. Ctrl+click is working as an okay substitute so far.

Comment: That's really odd. You're able to select with ctrl+click, but alt-click isn't working? What OS are you on?